# Celery chain not executing tasks after executing a group

Tags: python-2.7, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using RabbitMQ version "3.5.7" and Celery 4.0.2 in my [project](https://github.com/vijeth-aradhya/celery-priority-tasking/).

This is the code which creates the Celery chain in [this file](https://github.com/vijeth-aradhya/celery-priority-tasking/blob/master/celery_sample_project/main.py):

```
@app.route('/transcodeALL', methods=['POST'])
def transcodeToALL():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # We will do something like this to simulate actual processing of a video
        transcoding_tasks = group(
            transcode_1080p.signature(queue='tasks', priority=1, immutable=True),
            transcode_720p.signature(queue='tasks', priority=2, immutable=True),
            transcode_480p.signature(queue='tasks', priority=3, immutable=True),
            transcode_360p.signature(queue='tasks', priority=4, immutable=True)
        )
        main_task = chain(
            common_setup.signature(queue='tasks', immutable=True)
            transcoding_tasks,
            end_processing.signature(queue='tasks', immutable=True),
        )
        main_task.apply_async()
        return 'Video is getting transcoded to all dimensions!'
    else:
        return 'ERROR: Wrong HTTP Method'
```

Here, `common_setup` is being called and then the group `transcoding_tasks` is also being called after that. But, `end_processing` is not called at all.

Somehow, after the group is executed, no other task is called. I've switched the statements in the chain [here](https://github.com/vijeth-aradhya/celery-priority-tasking/issues/2) and checked, and the same problem occurs!

Am I  doing something trivially wrong or is this a bug?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Solution found!

Answer (score 1):

This was quite an interesting bug! It took sometime to figure out that result backend should be some persistent backend like SQL or Redis.

So, I made [this](https://github.com/vijeth-aradhya/celery-priority-tasking/commit/16431002e3646a49af1516c1a9832b4f7597aaca) modification in Celery config:

```
-    celeryconfig['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'amqp://'
+    celeryconfig['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost'
```

And, Celery chains (and chords) work perfectly.
Hope it helps!

Comment: For me it's redis only. but still not end task is not called.